# What is the difference between INSTR and LIKE in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Can some one tell me the difference between `INSTR` and `LIKE` in Oracle?

Which one is faster in Oracle10g?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197026/is-substr-or-like-faster-in-oracle

Comment: For [MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451608/which-is-faster-instr-or-like) this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171511/480894) says that INSTR is faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends on the data and on the pattern. If you use `like 'a%'`, then Oracle can use a BTree indexes to look up the matches because it can search the btree with the start of the pattern and then consider only the subtree.

This doesn't work for `LIKE '%a'` but you can work around this by creating a calculated column which reverses all values from the column you want to search (so you get the pattern above).

If you use hashed indexes, there is little that Oracle can do but scan the whole index. It might sill be faster when there are only few different values.

I'm not sure whether `INSTR` can ever use an index because it has no fixed anchor.

So like with all performance questions:

1. Fill the database with some realistic test data and run some tests.
2. Always write your code in a way that it can be optimized easily later, when you **know** about the bottlenecks
3. Never guess what might be slow. You'll be wrong 90% of the time. Always measure.

Answer (score 3):

- [INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) searches for a string inside another string, with options for direction, starting positions etc
- [LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm#sthref2798) is simple pattern matching and standard SQL

Neither will be "faster" consistently because they aren't comparable: it depends what you need to do, your data, how you search etc

Answer (score 2):

[INSTR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) is a oracle function since Oracle 8i for finding a substring, and [LIKE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php) is an SQL condition mainly used for matching string with wildcards.

I expect INSTR to be a bit faster since it's less complex but I didn't measure it.

Comment: Maybe INSTR is less complex but the performance of a statement does not depend if a function used uses some cpu cycles more or less for evaluation but from how much data must be retrieved and evaluated to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

This page says that `INSTR` is faster:

http://oracle.veryoo.com/2013/03/performance-comparation-between-like.html

EDIT:
Archive link since the above is no longer available:
http://web.archive.org/web/20160301212009/http://oracle.veryoo.com/2013/03/performance-comparation-between-like.html

Also on SO for [MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451608/which-is-faster-instr-or-like) this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171511/480894) says that INSTR is faster.

Comment: the page isn't available.

Comment: Thank you that you searched vor a valid link. But I have other complaints, too. On stackexchange answers that contain only links aren't appreciated. The relevant content  of the link should be presented in the post, too. But I think the measurements presented in this link are of no relevance. The comparison is between `instr(title,' manual')>0` and `title like'%manual%'` The first expression searches for titles starting with 'manual' and the latter for titles that contain 'manual' anywhere.

Comment: Besides that we are told that the table has 11 Mio. rows and we see the elapsed times, We don't know the structure of the tables, the length of the title field, no execution plans, no statistics, nothing about the test environment. This test should be ignored.

Comment: [here is an experiment that has been conducted on a mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2451665/754550) (and lacks the same additional information as the experiment in your link): the result is that there is no difference

Comment: @miracle173 `instr(title,'manual')>0` will search for titles which have 'manual' anywhere exactly like `like` does. [INSTR documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564)

Comment: @miracle173 from the link that you provided, this answer says that [INSTR is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171511/480894)

Comment: yes, I was wrong with the INSTR function, it works as you describe.  The answer you are referencing does not fetch data at all, it calls a function that 100 000 000 repeats the same operation on the  same strings and measures that 'like' needs 4 seconds mor, so for only 10 000 000 repetitions it will take 0.4 seconds longer. Assume we have similar numbers for Oracle. Can you tell me why in the article you are referencing Oracle needs 20 seconds more when using 'like'? This is 500 times larger than 0.4. The numbers in the article you link to in your answer do not make sense.

Comment: @miracle173 I don't know. Maybe Oracle just has a different implementation?