# how to fetch data of employees which lastname start with 'P' or 'D' or 'SN' or 'AD'

Tags: sql, oracle

i tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES_MASTER 
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE 'P%' OR FIRST_NAME LIKE 'D%' OR FIRST_NAME LIKE 'SN%'OR 
FIRST_NAME LIKE 'AD%';
```

but are there any other solution for that ??

Comment: you can do the same task in many ways, like by using substring, but what purpose would it solve ? what you are doing currently looks fine to me

Comment: That's probably how I'd do it. No need to get fancy, simple works.

Comment: What database are you using (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres) ?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: i am using oracle

Comment: Well you could use the lastname column instead of `FIRST_NAME` if it is lastname you want to match :)

Comment: @primitpatel Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197026/is-substr-or-like-faster-in-oracle) as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEES_MASTER
WHERE REGEXP_lIKE(LAST_NAME,'^(P|D|SN|AD)');
```